# Stumped on Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a count of the field WOID  for a specific date the trouble is that the date field [opendate] is a date time field so I decide to use cast to change [opendate] to a date field

```
SELECT distinct
   cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date]
  ,count([WOID]) as ID
FROM [Tasks]
Group by [OPENDATE]
```

The problem is I get output like this

```
Opened date ID 
2014-05-01  1
2014-05-01  1
2014-05-21  1 
2014-05-20  1
```

where I would expect to get the proper count like this

```
Opened date ID 
2014-05-01  4
2014-05-02  5
```

Any thoughts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are grouping by something different than what you are selecting, change to:

```
SELECT cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date]
      ,count([WOID]) as ID
FROM [Tasks]
Group by cast([OPENDATE] as date)
```

You may be after a count of distinct `WOID` per date, in which case you'd use:

```
SELECT cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date]
      ,count(DISTINCT [WOID]) as ID
FROM [Tasks]
Group by cast([OPENDATE] as date)
```

As a general rule, any non-aggregate items in your `SELECT` should be included in your `GROUP BY`.  `DISTINCT` becomes redundant and can be excluded.

Comment: My guess is that the `distinct` was added in hopes that it would fix the Group By problem solved by the first Select.

Answer (score 0):

Give:

```
SELECT distinct
   cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date]
  ,count([WOID]) as ID
FROM [Tasks]
Group by cast([OPENDATE] as date)
```

a shot - you want to group it on the `date`, not the `datetime` - mimicking your selected column

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want a count of distinct WOID's.  If so:

```
SELECT 
   cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date]
  ,count(distinct [WOID]) as ID
FROM [Tasks]
Group by cast([OPENDATE] as date)
```

Comment: Ah I see I did not realize you could use distinct ith in the count function. I'll test and mark as answer in a bit

Answer (score 0):

More complex solution can be the following.

First of all, you receive the set in the needed format:

```
SELECT cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date] ,[WOID] as ID
FROM [Tasks]
```

Then, using the above, you can perform the grouping and counting as you want, for example:

```
SELECT [Opened Date], ID = count([WOID])
FROM
(
    SELECT cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date], [WOID]
    FROM [Tasks]
) x
Group by [Opened Date]
```

If you want to count the unique values of the WOID per datte, you can modify the query as following:

```
SELECT [Opened Date], ID = count(distinct [WOID])
FROM
(
    SELECT cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date], [WOID]
    FROM [Tasks]
) x
Group by [Opened Date]
```

if you want to use the window functions, the query may looks as following:

```
SELECT distinct
   cast([OPENDATE] as date) as [Opened Date] ,
   count([WOID]) over (partition by cast([OPENDATE] as date) order by [WOID]) as ID
FROM [Tasks]
```